# Grabbing a script TAG on a web then to an object/arr

Tags: javascript, html

I can grab a script tag from a website but it returns a string. I wish I could use getElementByTagName but it is not an option at the moment.

Here is an example of what it returns:

```
"/n/tvar whatTheHell = 1234;\n
  \t\tvar ojb = {
  \t\tfoo : \"bar\",
  ... 
}"
```

I've tried eval and had no luck. I tried a npm package call "code-stringify" and still no luck.

any suggestions?

Comment: I think your first chars should be `\n\t` and not `/n/t`

Comment: Thanks mplugjan for editing the question. But that was what I literally get on my screen :)

Comment: /n/t are not valid chars

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```js
var str = `\n\tvar whatTheHell = 1234;\n
  \t\tvar ojb = {
  \t\tfoo : \"bar\",
  ... 
}`

console.log(decodeURIComponent(str))
```